# i want to save an ical4j Calendar object using proto dataStore, but i cant update it

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers

when i want to call the .toBuilder() function i get an unresolved Reference error

```
dataStore.updateData {
            it.toBuilder().setSavedEvents(newCalendarObject).build()

        }
```

i figured it could be, because i used a kotlin data class to introduce the structure, and not a .proto file, so i tried to make a proto file, that does the same thing, but i cant import the ical library into my .proto file. How can i import external librarys into my proto file, or is there another reason, that the function cant be found? thx